# Cut first 3 words of each element of the string in python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to cut first 3 words of each element of the string,  skipping whitespace, dots and dash

example:

```
["Spanish.1 Spanish Spanish, Catalan-2 3 6, English, Portuguese-4, Italian.5 Italy 2-It"]
```

needs to become

```
"Spanish.1 Spanish, Catalan-2 3, English, Portuguese-4, Italian.5 Italy"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite the clearest question, but I suspect that this does the trick:

```
inString = "Spanish.1 Spanish Spanish, Catalan-2 3 6, English, Portuguese-4, Italian.5 Italy 2-It"
outString = ', '.join([' '.join(x.split(' ')[:2])
                       for x in inString.split(', ')]
print(outString)
```

Which is a bit hard to understand, so split into sections it goes as follows:

```
inString = "Spanish.1 Spanish Spanish, Catalan-2 3 6, English, Portuguese-4, Italian.5 Italy 2-It"          
a = inString.split(', ')
b = [' '.join(x.split(' ')[:2])
     for x in a]
outString = ', '.join(b)
```

First we split the input string by cutting along the commas. Then for every section we now have we again split it, but on the spaces, and take only the first two elements of the list that gets created that way. Those two pieces are joined back together. By doing all that in a list comprehension we are left with `b` that we can join the elements of to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I finally understood what you meant..
This should do it. In future it might help if you explain what your code does -
Essentially, you have multiple sentences (marked out by the ','). In your sentences, you have words (separated by whitespace). These words can be a number as well.

```
s = "Spanish.1 Spanish Spanish, Catalan-2 3 6, English, Portuguese-4, Italian.5 Italy 2-It"

# split by comma, remove spaces at extreme left/right
sentences = s.split(",")
sentences = [sentence.strip() for sentence in sentences]

new_final_sentence = ""
for sentence in sentences:
    # split by space, delete away every third element
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    if len(words) >= 3:
        del words[3-1::3]
    
    new_sentence = " ".join(words)
    new_final_sentence += new_sentence + ", "

print(s)
print("became...")
print(new_final_sentence)
```

In future it definitely helps if you are able to explain/describe your issue more, or if you are not sure of the terminologies yet, then more or similar examples usually help.

Comment: your welcome. in future it will definitely help if you are able to explain or describe your issue more. if you're not sure of the terminologies/how to describe, having more or similar examples help. Maybe even showing the code you tried as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean, but if it is in a list, you can you the `del list[0:3]`, and if it is a string, you can slice like `string[:3]` to cut the first three elements.